# Trigger build via URL gives me no crumb included in request error

Tags: jenkins

I've been trying to trigger a build via the Jenkins API so far with no success. I configured a job on 'Trigger builds remotely' and set a token, 'abc'.

Then in postman I did a post to:

```
$jenkinsurl:$port/job/$jobname/build?token=abc
```

And the response is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /job/DCD%20Specifications/build. Reason:

        <pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <i>
        <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
    </i>
    <hr/>
</body>
```

I also tried to use basic authentication with a valid username and password, but to no avail.

I can use gets to retrieve whatever information I want from the Jenkins API just fine; it's only this post that gives me this problem.

I had Jenkins 2.7 and updated to 2.19.4 and both versions give me this problem. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137760/jenkins-rest-api-create-job

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497819/trigger-parameterized-build-with-curl-and-crumb

Comment: For me helped changing jenkins url from
`https://my-jenkins-url`
to
`https://my-jenkins-url/bitbucket-hook/`

Answer (score 4):

Pass in POST headers, "Jenkins-Crumb:5740ac1b614ca59f5dd5ef151b2895b3".

Your Crumb can be obtained from the URL http://jenkins:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml

In the POST body, use the appropriate Jenkins XML API request.

Here is my [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)  images with parameters:

[image: Postman Jenkins Jenkins-Crumb]

Comment: How can this be used with bitbucket webhook? `https://myjenkins-url/bitbucket-hook/`

Answer (score 3):

**This worked for me:**

**Obtain crumb**

`$ wget -q --auth-no-challenge --user yourUserName --password yourPassword--output-document - 'http://myJenkins:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'`

**Now run the Jenkins job**

`$ curl -I -X POST http://yourUserName:yourPassword@myJenkins:8080/job/JOBName/build -H "Jenkins-Crumb:44e7038af70da95a47403c3bed5q10f8"`

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created 
Date: Fri, 28 July 2017 09:15:45 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
Location: http://myJenkins:8080/queue/item/17/
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Yes, the user/password thing is also needed for running the Jenkins job.

Comment: Using Wget for running the Jenkins job, I found "`=`" was required for specifying the value `Jenkins-Crumb` (not "`:`"); the parameters to Wget were `--auth-no-challenge --user SomeUserName --password $MYPASSWORD --post-data="Jenkins-Crumb=4c69243fb6d96efd69..."`