# How can I trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)?

Tags: jenkins

How do I trigger builds remotely?

I followed some tutorial and ready with this below:

```
Curl user `sanveen:585da82e7d3df2991dea3533ea794d06 `
```

The `M` link format is `http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/triggerbuild/build?token=gitbitsolution6789`

The authentication token set in the jenkins-plugins section.

But where do I call this and trigger the build?

Comment: Lets suppose you have two machines A and B. On machine A jenkins is configured. And your purpose is to trigger builds from machine B. In order to do that you configure jenkins to allow builds using scripts. and make an http request to machine A from machine B.

Comment: Is there  way to save this  settings in. Sh  file and trigger the build once committed? I want  to trigger the build now..please  provide me the steps to do it

Comment: Yes. Surely you can put that command in .sh file and run that. You can do that from terminal as well

Comment: Thank you Talha. I opened git bash and created hooks.sh by vi editor.Added these comment Curl user sanveen:585da82e7d3df2991dea3533ea794d06 http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/triggerbuild/build?token=gitbitsolution6789 and run the script file. Before running the script, i set the anonymous user access in jenkin security. Jenkin build triggered successfully. However i got this message "Could not resolve host: user" after run the script file

Comment: You should always have security in place to avoid from attacks.
For this issue you can post another question.

Comment: See also *[Trigger build via URL gives me no crumb included in request error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884446/trigger-build-via-url-gives-me-no-crumb-included-in-request-error/45396361#45396361)*.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have two machines A and B. On machine A Jenkins is configured. And your purpose is to trigger builds from machine B. In order to do that you configure Jenkins to allow builds using scripts. And make HTTP [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) requests to machine A from machine B.

To send POST requests to machine B, you can make use of curl and create a Bash script to trigger a build.

For example,

```
curl -X POST http://API_TOKEN_USER_ID:API_TOKEN@your-jenkins.com/job/JobName/build?token=AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN
```